# fprintf is not printing the data into the file

Tags: c

I have written a code in C. Inside the for loop in main(), I have written the following. When I run the code, the fprintf statement is not writing the data into the datafile. I am adding edges to a graph. While adding, I am checking whether the pairs are already in the list using adjacent list. If the pairs are not in the list, I am adding the edges, using the function call addEdge():

```cpp
int main()
{

        FILE *ed = NULL;
        ed = fopen("c2.txt","w");
        FILE *ls = NULL;
        ls = fopen("e2.txt", "w");
        FILE *lk = NULL;
        lk = fopen("link2.txt","w");
        if(ls == NULL){
        printf("Error in opening file ls!\n");}
        if(ed == NULL){
        printf("Error in opening file ed!\n");}
        if(lk == NULL){
        printf("Error in opening file lk!\n");}
        else 
        {
            int src,dest;
            int src1,dest1;
            int i,k,v;
            int NV  = 500   #No. of nodes
            int m  = 10000 #No. of edges
            int nblinks = 0; # edge counter:
            double x[NV],x1[NV];
            double x2[NV];
            unifRand(x,x1,x2); // function call for infection rate:Pass only name of array:
            int ss[NV];
            data1(ss);       // function call for generated data:
            double sum,sum1 = 0.0;
            double R = 0.00268; //Learning rate: // (i) 0.01 // ii. 0.001 // (iii) 0.00251 (iv)0.00268
            double L[NV][NV-1];
            double L1[NV][NV-1];
            double L_old[NV][NV-1];
            double L2[NV][NV-1];
            double t = 0, dt = 0.1;
            double C; 
            struct Graph* graph  = createGraph(NV); // Function call for graph:
            int d;
            int nblinks = 0;     // Edge counter:
            L_old[0][1] = 0.01; // choice of initial coupling/guess : 0.02


            for(i=0; i<NV-1; i++)
            {

                 x2[i] = 0.02; 

             }

            fprintf(ed,"True\t\tMeasured\t x[i]\t\t x1[i]\t\t x2[i]\t\tsum\t\t Error\t\ttime\tnode\n");
            fprintf(ed,"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            fprintf(lk," Pair of Nodes:\n");
            fprintf(lk,"---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");




    for( i = 0, k = 1; i < NV-1; i++)
    { 

            struct AdjListNode* temp = graph->array[i].head; 
            printGraph(graph, &sum, temp);
            # if the adjacent node is not zero: 
            while(temp != NULL && temp->next != NULL)
            { 

                 fprintf(ls,"%d %d\n", i, temp->dest);
                 temp = temp->next;
                  while(nblinks < m)  
                  { 

                  #Random numbers for source and destination nodes:
                  int src1 = random()%NV;
                  int dest1 = random()%NV;

                  if(src1 < dest1)
                  {
                      src  = src1;
                      dest = dest1;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      src = dest1;
                      dest = src1;
                   } 

                 int pairs[2] = {src, dest};
                 //If pairs are not in the list, add the edges then:  
                 if(src != dest && pairs[2] != (i, temp->dest)) 
                 {

                  printf("%d\t%d\n",src,dest);
                  fprintf(lk,"(%d,%d)\t(%d,%d)\n", pairs[0],pairs[1],i, temp->dest);
                  addEdge(graph, src, dest);
                  nblinks++; // counter:


                  }  // End if


                 }   //End while1 :


                 }   // End while 2:

            # I have written my calculation here   :
            fprintf(ed,"%0.6lf\t%0.6lf\t%0.6lf\t%0.6lf\t%0.5lf\t\t%0.6lf\t%0.6lf\t%0.1lf\t%d\t%0.6lf\n", L[i][k],L1[0][1],x[i],x1[i], 
         x2[i],sum1,C, t,ss[k],L2[i][k]);  
              }  // End for
        }        // End else

       fclose(ed); 
       fclose(ls); 
       fclose(lk);
       ed = NULL; 
       ls = NULL; 
       lk = NULL;
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `ls`? Where is it defined? Is *for* loop really meant to go to `i < NV-1` nodes?

Comment: I have added my more details now. ls is defined  and  i should go through all nodes. I've also closed the file descriptors in my coding.

Comment: You don't write anything but the header to ed.

Comment: Your error handling in case of failing `fopen`s is wrong.

Comment: c2.txt is working. The problem is only with e2.txt and link2.txt

Comment: It's time now to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: Yes, I run my code with gdb. It shows[Inferior 1 (process 7130) exited normally]

Comment: Then what stops you from stepping through your code and investigate what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This code is quite strange and some parts of it should not be compiled by c compiler.

E.g.:

```
        int NV  = 500   #No. of nodes
        int m  = 10000 #No. of edges
        int nblinks = 0; # edge counter:
```

where `#No. of nodes` is like comment and `int NV  = 500` has no `;` in the end - so is not completed line of code.

Style is also not perfect, e.g.:

```
    if(ls == NULL){
    printf("Error in opening file ls!\n");}
    if(ed == NULL){
    printf("Error in opening file ed!\n");}
    if(lk == NULL){
    printf("Error in opening file lk!\n");}
    else 
    {
```

should be

```
    if(ls == NULL)
    {
          printf("Error in opening file ls!\n");
          return 1;
    }
    if(ed == NULL)
    {
          printf("Error in opening file ed!\n");
          return 1;
    }
    if(lk == NULL)
    {
          printf("Error in opening file lk!\n");
          return 1;
    }
    // no else needed after 3 way to the exit (return)
```

or better

```
    if(!lk || !ed || !ls)
    {
          printf("Error in opening on of the files\n");
          return 1;
    }
```

In general, if all files are opened in the required mode (and after all writing are closed) no problem should be with `fprintf` except incorrect format string or wrong data for output.

**UPDATE:**

Just to check output, you can use `stdout` as the first argument of `fprintf` to see result at the screen (console), or make `lk = stdout;` instead of `lk = fopen("link2.txt", "w");`.

Then if you see data at the screen look what is wrong with the file.

Comment: Thank you very much  for the very detailed suggestion and let me try now. In the original program, I have written  as follows only. While posing the query here, I've made this mistake and I am sorry int NV  = 500;   // No. of nodes    
        int m  = 10000;  // No. of edges
        int nblinks = 0;  // edge counter:

Comment: Pay attention that expressions like `double x2[NV];` require from `NV` to be a constant expression in C

Comment: I've rewritten in the above format. when I give lk = stdout, its not printing anything.

Comment: I've defined NV = 500 as a global declaration

Comment: Found the bug finally..The assumption pairs[2] != (i, temp->dest) and the outer while loop causes the error.